# Assign javascript variable from ASP value

Tags: javascript, asp-classic

I have a page where I need to assign ASP variables into javascript variables that are then used to copy form fields when you click a checkbox (address info submitted on a previous page using ASP). The javascript variables do have values being set from the ASP Request.Form as I have verified this in view source on the page where this form is.

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/JavaScript">
<!--
function CheckBillingAddress() 
{

var theForm = document.form1;
var Address = "<%=Request.Form("Corp_Address1")%>";
var Address2 = "<%=Request.Form("Corp_Address2")%>";
var City = "<%=Request.Form("Corp_City")%>";
var Prov = "<%=Request.Form("Corp_Province")%>";
var Postal = "<%=Request.Form("Corp_Postal")%>";

 if (theForm.BillingAddOption.checked == true)
 { 
    theForm.BillingAddress1.value = Address.value; 
    theForm.BillingAddress2.value = theForm.Address2.value; 
    theForm.BillingCity.value = theForm.City.Value; 
    theForm.BillingProv.value = theForm.Prov.value; 
    theForm.BillingPostalCode.value = theForm.Postal.value; 

 }

if (theForm.BillingAddOption.checked == false)
 {
    theForm.BillingAddress1.value = '' 
    theForm.BillingAddress2.value = ''; 
    theForm.BillingCity.value = ''; 
    theForm.BillingProv.value = ''; 
    theForm.BillingPostalCode.value = ''; 
 }
}
//-->
</script>
```

My HTML form is:

```
<form name="form1" method="post" action="#" onsubmit="return(ProcessSubmit(this));" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
          <table  width="80%" align="center" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="1" class="formtable2">
        <tr valign="baseline"  align="center"> 
          <td colspan="2" valign="middle" class="FormSubHdr"><h3><b> 
            BILLING &amp; SHIPPING INFORMATION </b></h3></td>
        </tr>
                    <tr valign="baseline"> 
          <td valign="middle" align="right"  width="45%"><b>* 
            First Name: 
            </b></td>
          <td width="55%" align="left" valign="middle" > 
            <input type="text" class="GrFormBG" name="FirstName" size="30" maxlength="50"> 
          </td>
        </tr>
     <tr valign="baseline"> 
          <td valign="middle" align="right"  width="45%"><b>* 
            Last Name: </b></td>
          <td width="55%" align="left" valign="middle" > 
            <input type="text" class="GrFormBG" name="LastName" size="30" maxlength="60"> </td>
        </tr>
        <tr valign="baseline" > 
          <td valign="middle" align="right" width="45%" > 
            <p><b>Email 
              Address:&nbsp;</b></p>
          </td>
          <td width="55%" align="left" valign="middle" > 
            <%=Request.Form("Email")%> </td>
        </tr>
        <tr valign="baseline">
          <td valign="middle" align="right"><b>Also send emails to this address: </b></td>
          <td align="left" valign="middle" ><input name="Email2" type="text" class="GrFormBG" id="Email2" size="25" maxlength="60"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr valign="baseline">
          <td valign="middle" align="right"><strong>*Billing Address:</strong></td>
          <td align="left" valign="middle" ><input name="BillingAddOption" type="checkbox" id="BillingAddOption" value="Same as Corporate Address" onclick="CheckBillingAddress()">                Same as Corporate Address</td>
        </tr>
        <tr valign="baseline"> 
          <td valign="middle" align="right"  width="45%"><b> 
            * 
            Billing Address Street: 
            </b></td>
          <td width="55%" align="left" valign="middle" > 
            <input type="text" class="GrFormBG" name="BillingAddress1" size="30" maxlength="80">
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr valign="baseline"> 
          <td valign="middle" align="right"  width="45%"><b>Billing 
            Address 2: </b></td>
          <td width="55%" align="left" valign="middle" > 
            <input type="text" class="GrFormBG" name="BillingAddress2" size="30" maxlength="50">
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr valign="baseline"> 
          <td valign="middle" align="right"  width="45%"><b>* 
            Billing City: 
            </b></td>
          <td width="55%" align="left" valign="middle" > 
            <input type="text" class="GrFormBG" name="BillingCity" size="30" maxlength="50">
          </td>
        </tr><tr valign="baseline">
          <td valign="middle" align="right"  width="45%"><b>*
            Billing Province:
            </b></td>
          <td width="55%" align="left" valign="middle"><select name="BillingProv" id="BillingProv">
            <option value="">select State or Province (Canada/US Only)</option>
            <option value="ZZ">Outside US or Canada</option>
            <optgroup label="United States">
              <option id="USA-AL" value="AL">Alabama (AL)</option>
              <option id="USA-AK" value="AK">Alaska (AK)</option>
              <option id="USA-AZ" value="AZ">Arizona (AZ)</option>
              <option id="USA-AR" value="AR">Arkansas (AR)</option>
              <option id="USA-CA" value="CA">California (CA)</option>
              <option id="USA-CO" value="CO">Colorado (CO)</option>
              <option id="USA-CT" value="CT">Connecticut (CT)</option>
              <option id="USA-DE" value="DE">Delaware (DE)</option>
              <option id="USA-DC" value="DC">District of Columbia (DC)</option>
              <option id="USA-FL" value="FL">Florida (FL)</option>
              <option id="USA-GA" value="GA">Georgia (GA)</option>
              <option id="USA-GU" value="GU">Guam (GU)</option>
              <option id="USA-HI" value="HI">Hawaii (HI)</option>
              <option id="USA-ID" value="ID">Idaho (ID)</option>
              <option id="USA-IL" value="IL">Illinois (IL)</option>
              <option id="USA-IN" value="IN">Indiana (IN)</option>
              <option id="USA-IA" value="IA">Iowa (IA)</option>
              <option id="USA-KS" value="KS">Kansas (KS)</option>
              <option id="USA-KY" value="KY">Kentucky (KY)</option>
              <option id="USA-LA" value="LA">Louisiana (LA)</option>
              <option id="USA-ME" value="ME">Maine (ME)</option>
              <option id="USA-MD" value="MD">Maryland (MD)</option>
              <option id="USA-MA" value="MA">Massachusetts (MA)</option>
              <option id="USA-MI" value="MI">Michigan (MI)</option>
              <option id="USA-MN" value="MN">Minnesota (MN)</option>
              <option id="USA-MS" value="MS">Mississippi (MS)</option>
              <option id="USA-MO" value="MO">Missouri (MO)</option>
              <option id="USA-MT" value="MT">Montana (MT)</option>
              <option id="USA-NE" value="NE">Nebraska (NE)</option>
              <option id="USA-NV" value="NV">Nevada (NV)</option>
              <option id="USA-NH" value="NH">New Hampshire (NH)</option>
              <option id="USA-NJ" value="NJ">New Jersey (NJ)</option>
              <option id="USA-NM" value="NM">New Mexico (NM)</option>
              <option id="USA-NY" value="NY">New York (NY)</option>
              <option id="USA-NC" value="NC">North Carolina (NC)</option>
              <option id="USA-ND" value="ND">North Dakota (ND)</option>
              <option id="USA-OH" value="OH">Ohio (OH)</option>
              <option id="USA-OK" value="OK">Oklahoma (OK)</option>
              <option id="USA-OR" value="OR">Oregon (OR)</option>
              <option id="USA-PA" value="PA">Pennsylvania (PA)</option>
              <option id="USA-PR" value="PR">Puerto Rico (PR)</option>
              <option id="USA-RI" value="RI">Rhode Island (RI)</option>
              <option id="USA-SC" value="SC">South Carolina (SC)</option>
              <option id="USA-SD" value="SD">South Dakota (SD)</option>
              <option id="USA-TN" value="TN">Tennessee (TN)</option>
              <option id="USA-TX" value="TX">Texas (TX)</option>
              <option id="USA-UT" value="UT">Utah (UT)</option>
              <option id="USA-VT" value="VT">Vermont (VT)</option>
              <option id="USA-VA" value="VA">Virginia (VA)</option>
              <option id="USA-VI" value="VI">Virgin Islands (VI)</option>
              <option id="USA-WA" value="WA">Washington (WA)</option>
              <option id="USA-WV" value="WV">West Virginia (WV)</option>
              <option id="USA-WI" value="WI">Wisconsin (WI)</option>
              <option id="USA-WY" value="WY">Wyoming (WY)</option>
              </optgroup>
            <optgroup label="Canada">
              <option id="CAN-AB" value="AB">Alberta (AB)</option>
              <option id="CAN-BC" value="BC">British Columbia (BC)</option>
              <option id="CAN-MB" value="MB">Manitoba (MB)</option>
              <option id="CAN-NB" value="NB">New Brunswick (NB)</option>
              <option id="CAN-NL" value="NL">Newfoundland and Labrador (NL)</option>
              <option id="CAN-NT" value="NT">Northwest Territories (NT)</option>
              <option id="CAN-NS" value="NS">Nova Scotia (NS)</option>
              <option id="CAN-NU" value="NU">Nunavut (NU)</option>
              <option id="CAN-PE" value="PE">Prince Edward Island (PE)</option>
              <option id="CAN-SK" value="SK">Saskatchewan (SK)</option>
              <option value="ON" selected id="CAN-ON">Ontario (ON)</option>
              <option id="CAN-QC" value="QC">Quebec (QC)</option>
              <option id="CAN-YT" value="YT">Yukon (YT)</option>
              </optgroup>
          </select></td>
        </tr>
        <tr valign="baseline">
          <td valign="middle" align="right"  width="45%"><b>*
            Billing Postal
            Code: </b></td>
          <td width="55%" align="left" valign="middle">
            <input name="BillingPostalCode" type="text" class="GrFormBG" size="7" maxlength="7"/>
<br> <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
</td>
        </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I can't see a question here.

Comment: **Danger**: This code is [vulnerable to XSS](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-site_Scripting_(XSS)). User input needs escaping before being inserted into an HTML document!.

Comment: You are using tables for layout and lots of obsolete attributes. Please learn about [HTML 5](http://w3.org/TR/html5/), [validation](http://validator.w3.org), [stylesheets](http://www.w3.org/wiki/Web_Standards_Curriculum#CSS) and [labels](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/200711/use_the_label_element_to_make_your_html_forms_accessible/).

Comment: Sorry its throwing an error:
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined 
The rest of the form is rather large and I know i'm using some older attribs but for now it is what it is.

Comment: @user2129560 There just string variables they won't have a `.value` property just remove the `.value` from `Address.value` for example. The `String` object in JavaScript doesn't have a `value` property. The `Request.Form` collection passes all values as strings. Also consider [@Quentin's comments](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25530258/assign-javascript-variable-from-asp-value#comment39858968_25530258) if you can.

Comment: Great that worked Lankymart! Now how would I set the proper dropdown value for the state/province?

Comment: I do have enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded"  in my form tag

Comment: @user2129560 I'm not sure you are approaching this right, the ASP `Request.Form` values could be placed directly into the HTML there is no need to pass them to JavaScript what purpose does it serve?

Comment: Its conditional as there could be a different address (one of three they provided earlier) the wanted to enter here. If I put it in automatically they might miss it and not enter the correct address.